# La propiedad es parte de la información clave del objeto y no se puede modificar

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

estoy realizando una una pequeña prueba y de funcionar pues incrusto el código en un proyecto grande en el que trabajo que es con **MVC**. mi problema es que intento insertar 4 registros utilizando el ciclo **for** pero al querer hacerlo me arroja el siguiente error

> The property 'idPermiso' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Este es mi Codigo

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var BD = new DATA.TESTEntities1())
        {
            var Unum = new DATA.Table_6();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
           {
                Unum.idPermiso = i;
                Unum.idUsuario = 55;
                Unum.idConvenio = 878;
                Unum.estaActivo = true;
                BD.Table_6.Add(Unum);
                BD.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

El inserta el primer registro de manera exitosa pero me falla cuando recorre el for y mi idPermiso se establece en 2

Mi tabla contiene 4 columna y me gustaria que me **INSERT** quedara de esta manera

```
idPermiso idUsuario idConvenio estaActivo 
    1        55        878         1
    2        55        878         1
    3        55        878         1
    4        55        878         1
```

La estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente la columna estaActivo es **[bit]** osea **true** y **false**.

El resto son de tipo **[bigint]** y **PRIMARY KEY** y no permite NULL

Que puede estar fallando en mi código que me lanza ese error?

Agradezco la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se produce porque luego de ejecutar `SaveChanges()` el objeto almacenado en `Unum` se convierte en parte del contexto. Eso se puede solucionar creando un nuevo objeto `Table_6` en cada iteración.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      var Unum = new DATA.Table_6();
      Unum.idPermiso = i;
      Unum.idUsuario = 55;
      Unum.idConvenio = 878;
      Unum.estaActivo = true;
      BD.Table_6.Add(Unum);
      BD.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias estimado, me quedo muy claro porque fallaba, Ya funciona perfectamente